# How best to parse and display Git patch (diff) info?

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to display Github patches, and I don't want to write my own parser. Specifically we are parsing the files.patch like in [this example from the Github API docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits).

I was hoping for something like [Google-Code-Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), but extensive Googling hasn't turned anything up. Is there anything to do this?

Comment: and what language do you want to use?

Comment: Using Backbone and making API calls to Github on the front-end, so Javascript

Answer (score 3):

[parse-diff](https://github.com/sergeyt/parse-diff) (CoffeeScript as well, but shouldn't matter as it can be used in any JS context) sounds a better (more widely used, maintained) option.

Answer (score 1):

Would [node-diff-parser](https://github.com/agate/node-diff-parser) help? Admittedly, it appears to be in CoffeeScript rather than straight JavaScript.

Alternatively, you could try [jonjonsonjr's diff-parse](https://github.com/jonjonsonjr/diff-parse) which looks to be in straight JavaScript.